# if @if(Auth::Check()) is used than it does not display the content on the screen

Tags: laravel-5

```
@if(Auth::check())
    <li><a href="{{ route('user.profile') }}">User Profile</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="{{ route('user.logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
@else
    <li><a href="{{ route('user.signup') }}">Signup</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ route('user.signin') }}">Signin</a></li>
@endif
```

here @if(Auth::Check()) is not working if used

Comment: try @if(Auth::user()) or @if(Auth::guard())

Comment: after using the @if(Auth::guard()) my else part is not working

Comment: are you sure you are logged out? Also, check your middleware.

Comment: in kernel.php I hide the  /**    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class, */ than it is working properly.